# SignalR + Redis backplane poor performance

Tags: redis, signalr

SignalR performance slows down with redis as backplane, its not able to push messages to client 200 per second, is there any thing wrong with the redis configuration or it is known behaviour

Comment: I've used Redis as a backing store for my SignalR instances with as many as 250 clients with multiple messages per second and I have not noticed any issues.  In addition, with the limited amount of information you have provided, it is impossible to give you any direction on what the solution might be.

Comment: As David L said, you haven't provided enough information to enable anyone to help you. Provide more details, and ideally a link to code, and we might be able to help.

Comment: Sorry for limited information, but i figured out the problem was with the older version of redis server 2.4 now I updated it to 2.8 with signar update to 2.1.2 and now it seems to work fine, thanks all